# Using Exception handling to fix foreign key constraint in PL/pgsql (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Trying to learn exception handling in pgSQL (PostgreSQL 9.1). The following SP fails with

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "dx" violates foreign key constraint "fk_icd9"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (cicd9, cdesc)=(244.9, testing1) is not present in table "icd9".
```

fk_icd9 is defined from table dx as:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_icd9 FOREIGN KEY (cicd9, cdesc)
  REFERENCES icd9 (cicd9, cdesc) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

My attempt at the SP is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION g_test() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    r View_dx%rowtype;
BEGIN
  r.cicd9 := '244.9';
  r.groupid := 'BBBB      CCCC        199971230';  
  r.tposted := '2013-08-30 17:45:45'::timestamp;
  r.cdesc := 'testing1';

  LOOP
    BEGIN
      UPDATE dx SET cdesc = r.cdesc
      WHERE cicd9 = r.cicd9 AND groupid = r.groupid AND tposted = r.tposted;
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN others THEN
        INSERT INTO icd9(cicd9, cdesc) VALUES (r.cicd9, r.cdesc);
    END;
    IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN;
    END IF; 
  END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am trying to update a table, dx, that has a foreign key constraint in a second table, icd9. If update of the dx table fails because of this constraint, then I would like to insert the new record in the parent icd9 table then loop back to the first table, dx, for update.

What am I doing wrong? How is this done?

Edit #1: Editing the code as shown below to:

```
 create or replace function g_savedx3() returns void as
$$
 DECLARE

_cicd9 character varying(8);
_groupid character varying(33);
_tposted timestamp without time zone;
_cdesc character varying(80); 


BEGIN
_cicd9 := '244.9';
_groupid := 'BBBBB        AAAAA        199998';  
_tposted := '2013-08-30 17:45:45'::timestamp;
_cdesc := 'testing109';

LOOP
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'About to update ';

        UPDATE dx SET cdesc = _cdesc
            WHERE 
                cicd9 = _cicd9 and 
                groupid = _groupid and tposted = _tposted;

        RAISE NOTICE 'Updated in g_saveDx3';

        IF FOUND THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;


        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN others THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'In exception g_saveDx3, about to insert';

                INSERT INTO icd9(cicd9,cdesc) VALUES (_cicd9, _cdesc);

                RAISE NOTICE 'In exception inserted';
    END;
END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select g_savedx3();
```

Yields the following messages:

NOTICE:  About to update
NOTICE:  Updated in g_saveDx3

ERROR:  insert or update on table "dx" violates foreign key constraint "fk_icd9"
DETAIL:  Key (cicd9, cdesc)=(244.9, testing109) is not present in table "icd9".
********** Error **********

ERROR: insert or update on table "dx" violates foreign key constraint "fk_icd9"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (cicd9, cdesc)=(244.9, testing109) is not present in table "icd9".

Note: I found an old entry on [updates violating foreign constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/14140.1086055511@sss.pgh.pa.us) by Tom Lane (2004)

> Yes it is ... you're expecting the RI triggers to fire during the
>   plpgsql function, but in fact they fire at completion of the outer
>   statement that called the plpgsql function.
>
> There's been some debate about whether this is really the most
>   desirable behavior, but that's how it is at the moment.

If this is still the case, it might explain the problem. Any ideas how to fix my code? (It should have worked??) Thanks.

***As mentioned below, I'm guessing this is the default behavior which, in my case, causes the exception to be called after completion of the plpgsql function. This behavior can be changed (PostgreSQL 9.1) with:

> SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE;

**WHICH IS NEEDED TO MAKE THIS WORK**

If it has any bearing, here is the definition of the ICD9 table:

```
 CREATE TABLE icd9
(
 recid serial NOT NULL,
 cicd9 character varying(8),
 cdesc character varying(80) NOT NULL,
 "timestamp" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
 modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
 chronic boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
 CONSTRAINT pk_icd9_recid PRIMARY KEY (recid),
 CONSTRAINT constraint_cdesc UNIQUE (cicd9, cdesc),
 CONSTRAINT desccheck CHECK (cdesc::text <> ''::text)
)
WITH (
 OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: What about checking if record exists in icd9, if not , insert. Then have the update code.

Comment: @Jayadevan Makes sense. But most of the time, a record will already exist in icd9. So I believe in general it would be faster to do the update first and catch the errors on the minority of the updates. I maybe wrong?

Comment: Your edit explains why this will not work. An obscure side-effect of the way that PostgreSQL works. You can achieve what you want to do with a so-called (modifed) `UPSERT` (many questions with answers on SO), but that violates your opening statement: Trying to learn exception handling. At least you learned not to combine FK violations with exception handling! And so did I {;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to old-fashioned debugging. Here is my code, it does insert.

```
create or replace function f () returns void as

$$
DECLARE
newval integer :=3 ;
BEGIN
LOOP
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'About to update ';
    UPDATE B SET ID2 = newval;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Updated ';
    IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN others THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'In exception , about to insert';
      INSERT INTO a VALUES (newval);
RAISE NOTICE 'In exception inserted';
END;
END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Execution:

```
select f();
NOTICE:  About to update 
NOTICE:  In exception , about to insert
NOTICE:  In exception inserted
NOTICE:  About to update 
NOTICE:  Updated
```

Table definitions:

```
test=# \d+ a
                           Table "w2gi.a"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer | not null  | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "a_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "b" CONSTRAINT "b_id2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES a(id)
Has OIDs: no
test=# \d+ b
                           Table "w2gi.b"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id1    | integer |           | plain   |              | 
 id2    | integer |           | plain   |              | 
Foreign-key constraints:
    "b_id2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES a(id)
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work! Please see my above edit (in question) with exacting code and errors. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks like it is the constraint checking (deferred) that is the issue. After the first begin , add  execute '  SET CONSTRAINTS  ALL  IMMEDIATE '; Then rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop you have

```
IF FOUND THEN
  RETURN;
END IF;
```

This ends the function before the loop goes into the next iteration after an `INSERT` because `FOUND` is set by that command too.

What you want is:

```
LOOP
  BEGIN
    UPDATE dx SET cdesc = r.cdesc
    WHERE cicd9 = r.cicd9 AND groupid = r.groupid AND tposted = r.tposted;
    IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN others THEN
      INSERT INTO icd9(cicd9, cdesc) VALUES (r.cicd9, r.cdesc);
  END;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Good to know about "Found" , but still fails with same error. Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: icd9(r.cicd9,r.cdesc) is never added to the ICD9 table, so is the EXCEPTION even being hit? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at Example 39-2 here : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: @Jayadevan Good example...that was my starting point. Problem is catching the exception from the update when a foreign key violation occurs; and fixing it. Thanks.

Comment: Does this explain why you are not able to do that ? http://postgresql.nabble.com/How-to-insert-in-a-table-the-error-returns-by-query-td5835771.html

Comment: @Jayadevan Hmm..maybe. However, I'm not using any transactions--at least, no explicit ones. Any idea on how to make this work? Thanks.